# Process stdout/stderr still showing up on monitor

Tags: linux

I have a process I am running on startup from my rc.local file:

```
setsid python /Path/To/script.py < /dev/zero &> /Path/To/log.txt &
```

However, when I boot the pi, the stdout is still being displayed on the monitor. If I instead run:

```
setsid python /Path/To/script.py > /Path/To/log.txt &
```

Everything works properly, why is the first command not working like it should?

Answer (score 1):

`&>log` is short hand for `>log 2>&1` in bash but rc.local is run with sh so that's why it's not working for you. So just use the long form.

Comment: Great! So, in my case it would look like:    setsid python /Path/To/script.py < /dev/zero > /Path/To/log.txt 2>&1 &